# Visited places map generator - by regions

Tags: online-resources, maps

I am looking for a map generator of visited places, where each country is split by regions/state. I.e. that it would be not possible to select country entirely, but only by its internal counties/states. For instance, I want to select particular states in USA or particular regions in Russia where I have been, but not the entire country.

Comment: Travbuddy has something similar however only Australia, USA, United Kingdom, and Canada and are broken down into states. http://www.travbuddy.com/world-travel-map

Comment: Probably because states, provinces, countries and republics  are not counties, districts, raions or oblasts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least I found it, it is [mytravelmap.xyz](http://www.mytravelmap.xyz/) (I am not affiliated with it).

Comment: Nice app, though it would be a lot better if you could zoom in and out, and having changing the default from "I was born there" sucks.

Answer (score 2):

Mapchart (not afflicted) at https://mapchart.net has the ability to do this to an extent. You will though have to select the country or region first in order together get more detailed choices for your map, if you select one of the world view types you'll only be able to fill in by country.

Comment: I didn't find where I can select different regions for Russia there for example

Comment: @Andremoniy Russia is available, scroll to the very bottom of the page and select it. Direct link: https://mapchart.net/russia.html

Answer (score -2):

I don't about any app but I have recieved one of these scratch maps on my birthday. I think it is more exciting to delete a place after you have visited on a map on your wall! https://www.luckies.co.uk/product/scratch-map-personalised-world-map-poster/

Comment: This a completely different medium and your answer does not answer the question, in my view.